# Bootstrap extend span columns to same height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have a row with an embedded object (span9) and an embedded iframe (span3)

The video I have managed to get to respond to various screen sizes, the iframe, however, stays a fixed size and doesn't even match the height of the embedded object beside it.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
  <div class="row-fluid">
<!--Video-->
<div class="span9">
   <div class="flex-video widescreen">
     <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="100%" width="100%" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=theabraxas" bgcolor="#000000"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=theabraxas&auto_play=true&start_volume=25" /></object>


   </div>
</div> 
<!--Chat-->
```

Here is the 'flex-video' css:

```
    .flex-video { position: relative;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-bottom: 67.5%;
height: 0;
margin-bottom: 16px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-video.widescreen { padding-bottom: 57.25%; }
.flex-video.vimeo { padding-top: 0; }

.flex-video iframe,
.flex-video object,
.flex-video embed {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

(EDIT 8/12-After looking more I see that JSFiddle seems to be used a lot for these types of issues, here's what I have for the row: http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6619/ Any advice would be tremendously appreciated)

I'm not much of a web/design person (let alone coder of _anything) so I won't copy in some of the other CSS, etc I've tried, but any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Edit: a live version of this, so you can see what I'm talking about, can be found at my test site here: http://theabraxas.us

Comment: Not much you can do with iframes from sites you don't control. You will probably have to go to the site that furnishes that embed and see if anyone has a solution. You can try http://embedresponsively.com/

Comment: `span9` and `row-fluid` are from Bootstrap v2, yet your question is tagged as Bootstrap v3?

Comment: Oh shoot, @cvrebert you're absolutely right - I had just assumed I was on Bootstrap 3 (again, 100% new to this, ~3 days in) Sorry about that I will try to update the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what you are looking for, I have a couple of things you might try:

1. Delete the parent's (`<div class="flex-video">`) `overflow: hidden` style, or change it to `overflow: visible`.  This will prevent the parent from hiding the extra content.  You can then change the iframe's height to whatever you deem appropriate.
2. Delete the parent's `height: 0` style and delete the iframe's `position: absolute` style.  Again, you can then change the iframe's height to whatever you want.
3. Change the parent's height to the same value as the iframe's height.

Any of these should work but they all require access to the parent element, so I hope you control that :)

Comment: Thanks for your post however the issue isn't specifying height on the iframe - if I specify it in pixels or other fixed measure it will scale to that. What I'm trying to accomplish is that the iframe extends vertically to the same length as the video embed to the left of it. I'm not sure if that helps any? Having 100% height just causes it to stick to 150px. *confusion*

Comment: Additionally, I copied the code in to this jsfiddle thing so that you can see exactly where the error is happening?  http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6619/

Comment: With the current setup on [theabraxas](http://theabraxas.us) try changing the "bigscreenChat" class by adding "position: absolute" and removing "width: 100%"

Comment: I added that and it did infact make the chat responsive, however it extends past the video chat? Any ideas? Here's a JSFiddle with updated information. http://jsfiddle.net/ydbsz5nr/

Comment: Sure, the iframe is set to 100% height; in this case it means 100% of the `<body>` height. Change the reference element to the `<div class="row-fluid">` element by giving it the `position: relative` style.

Comment: I added position:relative and removed position:absolute from the .bigscreenChat section, however it still appears to extend to the bottom. Should some other element be made relative?

` .bigscreenChat {
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 overflow:hidden;
} `

Comment: (giving you points now since you've already helped a ton! hope you won't vanish) what remains might have something to do with the <div class="span3"> not knowing it should be as tall as span9 or row-fluid?

Comment: The `position: absolute` is always in reference to the nearest containing element which has the style `position: relative`. If your iframe is inside your ".row-fluid" `div` and your want the iframe to take the entire height of the containing `div`, you need to make the ".fluid-row" `position: relative` and make the iframe `position: absolute`.

Comment: Firebug is a useful tool for debugging this type is issue, if you use Firefox / Iceweasel.  For instance, it can show you the size of certain elements and it lets you mess around with styles on the fly.